# How does does exponent property work on $\left(xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does 
$\left(xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x\right)$

become

$\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: $x=\dfrac{x}{1}=\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{1}}{\dfrac{1}{1}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{1}}{\dfrac{1}{1}}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{1}{x}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{1}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{x\cdot1}{1\cdot x}}{\dfrac{1\cdot1}{1\cdot x}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{x}}{\dfrac{1}{x}}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{x}}$

Answer (score 4):

$$\ xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x=x(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Because when you have the product of two terms, say $\ a\cdot b$, it is equivalent to $\ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}}\cdot b=\frac{b}{\frac{1}{a}}$

Answer (score 2):

Mosh answers your question from the **correct order** (perfect way), however I wanted to point out that you can go the other way too (and prove this).

Here is how :

$$\frac{(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)}{(\frac{1}{x})}=(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)\div \frac{1}{x}=(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)× x= xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x$$

---

Therefore:

$$\frac{(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)}{(\frac{1}{x})}=xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x$$

Answer (score 1):

With more intermediate steps :
$$\left(xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x\right)=$$
$$=x\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)$$
Let $x=\frac{1}{t}$ Replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{t}$
$$=\frac{1}{t}\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)$$
$$=\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}{t}$$
$t=\frac{1}{x}$ Replace $t$ by $\frac{1}{x}$
$$=\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

---

Another nice method :
$$\left(xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x\right)=$$
$$=\frac{x\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}{1}$$
Mulptiply the numerator and the denominator by the same term $\frac{1}{x}$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{x}x\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$
Simplify $\frac{1}{x}x=1$
$$=\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$